# How search multiple Xpath in CQ5 Querybuilder

Tags: java, xpath, aem, query-builder

i am using this query for content searching in single path.

```
map.put("path", "/var/root/FD/content/");
```

But i want to search content in two diiffrent folder path in a single query.
i have found like this we can do

```
map.put("group.p.or", "true");
map.put("group.1_path", "/var/root/FD1/content/");
map.put("group.2_path", "/var/root/FD2/content/");
```

But using like this taking very slow query performance because it searching from every folder path like here.

```
/var
/var/root/
/var/root/FD1/
/var/root/FD1/content/
/var
/var/root/
/var/root/FD2/
/var/root/FD3/content/
```

Is there any method is available to search multiple path in a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be XPath

/var/root//content/

will help you - it should match paths:

- /var/root/FD1/content/
- /var/root/FD2/content/
- /var/root/FD3/content/
- etc.